# Node.js cluster module appears to break Socket.io handshake

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, fork

I have the following simple WebSocket server built around the Socket.io library:

```
var PROCESSES = 1,
    cluster   = require('cluster'),
    i;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (i = 0; i < PROCESSES; i++) {
        console.log('Forking worker', i);
        cluster.fork();
    }
} else {
    (function () {
        var server = require('http').Server(),
            io     = require('socket.io')(server);

        io.on('connection', function (socket) {
            socket.on('message', function (message) {
                socket.emit('message', message + ' too!');
            });
        });

        server.listen(8080);
    })();
}
```

When started, it creates a single server process which listens for WebSocket connections and echoes a variation of the message back to the client:

```
$ iocat --socketio ws://localhost:8080
> i am hungry
i am hungry too!
> i like you
i like you too!
>
```

Now, when I change the `PROCESSES` variable to a number larger than 1, the client can no longer connect.

```
var PROCESSES = 2,
    ...
```

...results in...

```
$ iocat --socketio ws://localhost:8080
> client.on error
$ iocat -v --socketio ws://localhost:8080
> SIOClient> SIOClient: url-> ws://localhost:8080
SIOClient> onError { [Error: xhr poll error] description: 400 }
client.on error
```

My gut feeling is that the cluster module, when given more than one worker process, inappropriately switches from one process to another mid-handshake. But I would have thought that the entire connection, from the client initiating the handshake to the closing of the socket at the very very end, occurred over one persistent, keep-alive'd connection.

So what exactly is going on here? And how could it be worked around? I'm familiar with the idea of using a Redis store to share state between server processes on different machines, but that feels like too much infrastructure for my use case (collecting a stream of events from the client and replying with an acknowledgement).

**Versions:** socket.io@1.3.3, node@0.10.36, seen on OS X 10.10 and CentOS 6.6

Answer (score 2):

`socket.io` is not a simple wrapper over WebSockets, it does much more.  The opening handshake is an http request to decide on a protocol (WebSocket, polling, flash sockets, etc.) followed by, in your case, probably a WebSocket request.  If those hit different processes, the handshake will fail.

`socket.io` requires that you use sticky sessions, to ensure that a given client hits the same process each time.  They suggest using the [sticky-session module](https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session) if you want to use cluster.

Comment: Extrapolating on that, and using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14736178/1713313) from another question, it's impossible to load balance between two or more machines without using a Redis/etc. backend store?

Comment: @smitelli I don't think it supports a Redis backend anymore.  You just have to have your load balancer set up to do sticky routing.